# C++ nested class as template argument for parent

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I am trying to create a derived class that is using a nested class as a template argument for a parent class, but the compiler is unable to instanciate the template:

```
template<typename T>
class A {};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<typename B<T>::nested_class >
{
    class nested_class : public std::pair<std::string, T>
    {
        // adds methods that use the T type
    };
};
```

MSVC 2010 gives me 3 errors trying to compile this:

> syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'nested_class'
>
> 'nested_class' : undeclared identifier
>
> 'A' : use of class template requires template argument list

Moving the nested class out and making it separate solves the problem, but I want to understand why this doesn't compile.

Comment: Because the current instantiation (i.e. `B<T>`) is incomplete in the base-class list.

Comment: @Columbo more accurately, B<T>::nested_class isn't declared yet. Your can't forward declare nested classes, so you are SOL.

Comment: The code block compiles fine with MSVC 2013 and of course with GCC (I tried 4.7.3). This looks like a problem with the MSVC 2010 compiler which has been fixed since.